# When installing, command in `postinst` always results in `$?` = `0`

Tags: scripts, deb, packaging

I have a `postinst` script in my debian package:

```
#!/bin/bash

oqm-config -g system.hostname
RESULT="$?"
if [ "$RESULT" -eq 1 ]; then
  oqm-config -s system.hostname $(hostname).local "."
fi
```

This is intended to populate a config variable (if it doesn't exist). These commands function outside of the install process:

```
$ sudo ./test.sh 
+ oqm-config -g system.hostname
ERROR: Config key not found: system.hostname
+ RESULT=1
+ [ 1 -eq 1 ]
+ hostname
+ oqm-config -s system.hostname oqm-demo.local .
{
    "system": {
        "hostname": "oqm-demo.local"
    },
    "captain": {},
    "snapshots": {
        "location": "/data/oqm-snapshots/",
        "numToKeep": 5,
        "frequency": "weekly"
    }
}
```

However, when executed during install, the return code from the initial `oqm-config -g system.hostname` is always `0` (or more accurately empty string? unsure why this particular error from an empty string, should be `0`?):

```
Setting up open+quarter+master-manager-station+captain (1.0.18) ...
+ oqm-config -g system.hostname
ERROR: Config key not found: system.hostname
+ RESULT=0
+ '[' '' -eq 1 ']'
/var/lib/dpkg/info/open+quarter+master-manager-station+captain.postinst: line 5: [: : integer exp
ression expected
```

Am I missing something?

Building the debian file on Ubuntu 20.04, attempting install on `22.04`

Debian file: https://github.com/Epic-Breakfast-Productions/OpenQuarterMaster/releases/tag/manager-station%2Bcaptain-1.0.18

File that makes the debian (I know it's messy, but works [usually]): https://github.com/Epic-Breakfast-Productions/OpenQuarterMaster/blob/dev.388-fr-finish-keycloak-infra-component/software/Station-Captain/makeInstallers.sh#L107-L117

Comment: The given error makes no sense in the case of the script given. `RESULT=0`, but then in the line immediately after `RESULT` is empty. Is that the actual script you're using for `postinst`? Looks like something that might happen in a Makefile (each line run in its own shell). Also the output indicates `set -x` or `bash -x` is used, the script doesn't contain `set -x` and `sudo ./test.sh` isn't going to use `bash -x`.

Comment: Yes, that is the actual content of the script I place in the file `/DEBIAN/postinst`, minus me including `set -x` for debugging. I also agree, the value of `RESULT` when installing doesn't make sense

Comment: I swapped out the `postinst` of a random package with this script and can't repro. Which version of Ubuntu? How is the package built? Can you provide a minimal `debian/{rules,control,postinst}` that reproduces this?

Comment: I added a link to the deb file in the release, and a link to the script that produces it. I'll have to make a reproducer later, getting rather late here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
cat <<EOT >> "$buildDir/$debDir/DEBIAN/postinst"
#!/bin/bash

oqm-config -g system.hostname
RESULT=$?
if [ $RESULT -eq 1 ]; then
  oqm-config -s system.hostname $(hostname).local "."
fi

EOT
```

Bash performs parameter expansion, among other things, in [heredocs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents):

> If `word` is unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to
> parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion,
> the character sequence `\newline` is ignored, and ‘`\`’ must be used
> to quote the characters ‘`\`’, ‘`$`’, and ‘`` ` ``’.

(Here, `word` is the delimiter for the heredoc, `EOT` in this case.) That means that `$?` and `$RESULT` are expanded, and the heredoc writes the result of the expansion into the final input. You're relying on this behaviour [further down the script](https://github.com/Epic-Breakfast-Productions/OpenQuarterMaster/blob/dev.388-fr-finish-keycloak-infra-component/software/Station-Captain/makeInstallers.sh#L154).

You can see this in the final `postinst` file:

```
$ curl -sL https://github.com/Epic-Breakfast-Productions/OpenQuarterMaster/releases/download/manager-station%2Bcaptain-1.0.18/open+quarter+master-manager-station+captain_1.0.18_all.deb | dpkg-deb --ctrl-tarfile - | tar -xO ./postinst
#!/bin/bash
set -x
oqm-config -g system.hostname
RESULT="0"
if [ "" -eq 1 ]; then
  oqm-config -s system.hostname oqm-dev.local "."
fi

# /usr/share/update-notifier/notify-reboot-required
```

Quote the delimiter to prevent this from happening:

```
cat <<'EOT' > "$buildDir/$debDir/DEBIAN/postinst"
#!/bin/bash

oqm-config -g system.hostname
RESULT=$?
if [ $RESULT -eq 1 ]; then
  oqm-config -s system.hostname $(hostname).local "."
fi
EOT
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! That is in fact really good to know, and have some other things to update....